# DVD subtitle Using Vb6

Tags: vb6, wmp, dvd, subtitle

I would like to show, hide and choose the subtitle on a DVD film what I can play from vb6 code.
I use the wmp.dll.
I did not find help about changing (showing, hiding) the subtitles.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Ouch. I dont think you will find a lot of help there buddy... VB6 is kind of deprecated right now. Upgrade to VB.Net and use WPF so you can render your subtitles over a MediaElement and that would pretty much be it [Along with a helper thread that updates the subs according to time] May the force be with you.

Comment: You have the reason but i don't understand .net i'm Old scool , some day maybe (laughts), Thanks you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try the the [ClosedCaption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object.

Comment: After of 6 long months i have the answer, i take a snapshot from the Registry, I made a change in the configuration of the wmp (Change the language configuration), i take another registry snapshot, then  i found a RegKey, (change "0" to "1") i put these in My Code and Voila Work so fine, Thanks Anyway... i Love stackOverflow.